# How to define anonymous method types to build dynamic queries with LINQ?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, generics, linq-to-sql

I'm busy with a LINQ to SQL project that basically creates multiple threads for each entity type in my database, which constantly queries information from the DB in a thread.

Here's a pseudo example:

```
streamer.DefineDataExpression<Contacts>(x => x.FirstName == "Bob");
while(true)
{
     List<Contacts> MyContactsResult = streamer.ResultList;
     // do whatever with MyContactsResult
}
```

The above code doesn't exist, but this is what I have so far for the 'streamer' class (it obviously doesn't work, but you can see what I'm trying to achieve above):

```
public void DefineExpression(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    using (var db = new LINQDataContext())
    {
        ResultList = db.GetTable<T>().Where(expression);
    }
}
```

How do I go about creating a method like 'DefineExpression' that will allow me to query a LINQ type dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the [Dynamic LINQ provider, as mentioned by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).  I think that would give you everything you are looking for, because you can define the query as a string.  Therefore, you can more easily build a string representation of your query, and execute on the fly.